# Trying to find a short story about the ghost of a french officer who woos lady, kills husband

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, ghost

This was a really neat ghost story.  The plot:

- writer moves his family to an island to write in solitude
- his wife starts acting weird, is being seduced by the ghost of a French officer
- the ghost leads the wife away one rainy night, writer chases her through a grave yard
- writer trips and falls, hits his head on tombstone with the French officer's name on it
- the wife realizes that the ghost didn't want her, he only wanted to kill

Does anyone recognize this story?  If so, could you please share the title/author?
Thank you,
Mark

Comment: This sound like something from Guy de Maupassant. Project Gutenberg has something called [The Entire Original Maupassant Short Stories](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3090/3090-h/3090-h.htm) that you could search/skim.

Answer (score 5):

After an extensive Google search, I was finally able to find this short story. It is entitled **"[The Duel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74384)"** (1958) by Joan Vatsek.

From a [blog](https://gregwritesblog.com/2023/08/08/it-was-almost-like-a-song/):

> I did read one more story in *Alfred Hitchcock Presents My Favorites in Suspense*, “The Duel” by Joan Vatsek; another author I knew nothing about before reading the story. Joan was an author, had two stories in *Alfred Hitchcock Presents* anthologies, and was married to Robert Arthur, who worked on a lot of the anthologies and wrote ten of the first eleven Three Investigators novels. **The story, a ghost story about a writer and his wife, who had a breakdown of sorts, moving into his remote old family home–and before long, his wife begins communicating with a ghost in the house, who’d fought in the Revolutionary War and was killed at Yorktown…but had fought a number of dues in his life, usually with the husbands of women he’d seduced.** It’s quite a nasty little story, actually, and I was most impressed with it.

Comment: Great! If you could add any details that show why this is the right one, that would be helpful. Also, you should be able to accept your answer in two days.

Comment: I have the story in a Pan Collection of Ghost stories ed Alfred Hitchcock. It is by Joan Vatsek, as stated above. An excellent story